# Can you make an array of types in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

## Vivado Simulation cannot support unconstrained types which have a signed component to them.

i.e.

```
type A is array (natural range <>) of signed;
```

I have been using this in a design where type A is used in port declarations as I wish to have a parallel design which I control through a generic as well as the current stage word length e.g.

```
port (
inputdata : A(0 to number_of_parallel_generic-1)(stage_wordlength_generic-1 downto 0)
);
```

As I use the type A with many variations of the generics controling them e.g. 4 wide arrays with 16 wordlengths and other variations (often controled by a for generate loop)

```
for i in 0 to length_of_generate_statement-1 generate
    signal example_signal : A(0 to 3)(stage_wordlength_generic + i - 1 downto 0);
begin
    <functional code>
end generate;
```

This sort of code would allow me to gain bit growth from sequential sections of my archetecture - e.g. from an addition.

## Now... getting to the question at hand.

One way I could get round this rather than initiating a signal with a forever changing generate statement could actually be in the creation of an "array of types".

Lend me your eyes this is written in a not quite vhdl way but hopefully you can see what Im trying to do.

```
type my_arr_of_types is array(0 to length_of_array-1) of type;

for i in 0 to length_of_array-1 generate
    my_arr_of_types(i) <= <type declaration with some dependance on i>;
end generate;
```

Hopefully you can see what I am trying to do.

This would allow you to then call an element of the my_arr_of_types which itself is a type to then assign to a signal/variable.

i.e.
    signal my_sig : my_arr_of_types(n);

*Where n is any valid index of the array.

Obviously this is not allowed in VHDL or any simulation tool. But can anyone see a potential solution to my problem?

Remember I use most of these types on port statements so any solution has to fit within the limitations of the port declarations.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of the problem for which you provided the header **Vivado Simulation cannot support unconstrained types which have a signed component to them.** What is meant by 'signed component' here? Type numeric_std.signed is a two's complement representation and doesn't `gain bit growth from sequential sections of my archetecture - e.g. from an addition.`. You appear to be pursuing an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) solution and are not making your [specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clear.

Comment: Have you enabled VHDL-2008 support? VHDL-2008 support is very weak, don't expect too much ...

Comment: `A` is not a type, it's a signal (port), thus is cannot be used to declare a new signal like `example_signal`. If you like to declare a signal from an object, use the attribute `'subtype` like `signal example : A(0)'subtype;`.

Comment: Yes this is the thing @Paebbels i have 2008 syntax but just found out that Vivado doesnt support the array(natural range <>) of signed in simulation so am having to ompletely change my design/considering having to hard code everything... very fustrating that it is acceptiable in the IEEE 2008 standard but Xilinx are so slow to put it into practice

Comment: That's how Xilinx products work ... Even if xSim would support it, it doesn't mean that Vivado synth will support it too! What can you do? you can use e.g. two dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two dimensional arrays as a solution:

#### Package

```
library ieee;
use     ieee.numeric_std.all;

package utilities is
  type T_SLM is array(natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;
end package;
```

#### Entity

Now you can use this type in a port declaration together with two generic parameters. As sizes are now known in the architecture, you can create your used defined type of signed values and you can use either generate statements or a function to convert from the `T_SLM` to `myArray` type.

```
library ieee;
use     ieee.numeric_std.all;

library myLib;
use     myLib.utilities.all;

entity foo is
  generic (
    number_of_parallel : natural;
    stage_wordlength   : natural
  );
  port (
    Input : T_SLM(0 to number_of_parallel - 1, stage_wordlength - 1 downto 0)
  );
end entity;

architecture a of foo is
  type myArray is array (natural range <>) of signed(Input'range(2));

  function convert(matrix : T_SLM) return myArray is
    variable result : myArray(matrix'range(1));
  begin
    for i in matrix'range(1) loop
      for k in matrix'range(2) loop
        result(i)(j) := matrix(i, j);
      end loop;
    end loop;
    return result;
  end function;

  signal InputData1 : myArray(Input'range(1));
  signal InputData2 : myArray(Input'range(1));
begin
  genInput: for i in Input'range(1) generate
    genInput: for j in Input'range(2) generate
      InputData1(i)(j) <= Input(i, j);
    end generate;
  end generate;

  InputData2 <= convert(Input);
end architecture;
```

Many helper functions like this have been implemented in the [PoC Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) in package [PoC.vectors](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/vectors.vhdl?ts=2).